# PDO requires an absolute filesystem path rather than server url in PHP

Tags: php, apache, sqlite, pdo

I used to get this error

```
Error here: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file
```

when trying to open an SQLite connection using PDO, like this:

```
      $file_db = new PDO('sqlite:myfile.sqlite');
      $file_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
   PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Both **myfile.sqlite** and **index.php** are in the same folder.

However, I realized that using the real path of the sqlite file, ie something like **D:/Path/To/My/File/myfile.sqlite** actually worked.

I find this really scary, as a security breach, and I don't understand why this is happening?

I tried placing the file **myfile.sqlite** directly in **D:/** and it is still working, even though this is not an authorized directory in my Apache configuration.

Where is this coming from? http.conf? php.ini?

Thanks.

Comment: PHP has access to any file/directory on your filesystem (except cases with file access attributes)

Comment: right, I hadn't realized this. Now I am facing 2 problems: removing the Error mentioned above and preventing PHP to have access to my entire file system.

Comment: `$file_db = new PDO('sqlite:' . __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'myfile.sqlite');` Also you can't restrict php access to files. Just look at your code and make it safe.